# Pull variable up Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, refactoring

Is there any way to pull variable up outside try-catch block with shortcut? For example:

from:

```
try{
    AbstractList<Type> t1 = new ArrayList<Type>();
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

to

```
AbstractList<Type> t1;
try{
    t1 = new ArrayList<Type>();
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I know how to do this with a few shortcuts:

1. put your cursor on `t1` and then "Show intention actions".  From there, select "Split into declaration and assignment".  Your code will now look like this:

   ```
   try {
       AbstractList<String> t1;
       t1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Put your cursor on the line with the declaration.
3. Do the "move statement up" action.  Now your code will look like this:

   ```
   AbstractList<String> t1;
   try {
       t1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Move-up action is ctrl-shift-up, incidentally.

Comment: @vikingsteve yeah I feel bad I didn't give the keyboard shortcut keys, but I'm on a mac and used to a PC so I've changed a lot of my settings.  My shortcut keys aren't relevant to anyone but me.